# Getting an error while executing 'preload.js' in electron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm getting an error in which electronjs is not able to load preload script. I'm making a tool in which i can upload a text file and it will return me the content from the file.

[image: Electronjs Window]

I have file input with id 'upload' in my index.html.

**Main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });
  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  win.loadFile("index.html");
}

ipcMain.on("file-request", (event) => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    dialog
      .showOpenDialog({
        title: "Select the File to be uploaded",
        defaultPath: path.join(__dirname, "../assets/"),
        buttonLabel: "Upload",
        filters: [
          {
            name: "Text Files",
            extensions: ["txt", "docx"],
          },
        ],
        properties: ["openFile"],
      })
      .then((file) => {
        console.log(file.canceled);
        if (!file.canceled) {
          const filepath = file.filePaths[0].toString();
          console.log(filepath);
          event.reply("file", filepath);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
});
```

**preload.js**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
const uploadFile = document.getElementById("upload");

uploadFile.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ipcRenderer.send("file-request");
});

ipcRenderer.on("file", (event, file) => {
  console.log("Obtained File from main process: " + file);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by doing document selector thing in `renderer.js` and making `exposeInMainWorld` in `preload.js`